# Script for EPG (electronic program guide)

Tags: bash, epg

I need to make an EPG file witch is a tab delimited file from another doc.

For example:

```
2019.11.17.
8.30 Terminator 2
- Description for the movie
10.00 Terminator 3
- Description for the movie
12.00 etc..
```

and from this I need something like this

```
Terminator 2    2019-11-17 08:30:00 2019-11-17 10:00:00 Description for the movie
Terminator 3    2019-11-17 10:00:00 2019-11-17 12:00:00 Description for the movie
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: For this relatively simple code, you can use any tool with text processing capability: `awk`, `bash`, `python`, `perl`. If there are no constraints on implementation, go with the one that you are familiar with, and avoid solutions using compiled code (`c`, `java`, `c++`) - there is no need for those

Comment: I'm amazed, that EPG is still used. It seems to die out. May I ask on which project you are working?

Comment: @dude: Show your effort what you tried out, please. If the information is *always* 2 lines, this is trivial.